# Acceptable temperatures for an electric guitar

Tags: guitar, maintenance

There are plenty of subjects related to storing a guitar in various conditions, but most talk about exposure to direct sunlight or other notable sources of heat or are a bit vague.

My problem is that I live underneath the roof and during the summer heat waves it can get a little unbearable. I'm not 100% sure what the exact temperatures inside are (it can easily be over 30 degrees Celsius outside), but it's really uncomfortable.

Now, I don't plan to ever leave my electric guitar next to a heater (winter) or in direct sunlight. I am however worried about the effects of the general temperatures on my guitar if I just leave it in my room. There would be no sudden temperature changes (unless I actually decide to carry it downstairs - I can FEEL the temperature drop / rise going from floor to floor), it would just generally be warm during such days.

What are acceptable temperatures for an electric guitar? Should I be worried about mine? If these conditions aren't good is there anything I could do to make sure the guitar doesn't get damaged?

I could, of course, ask someone to store it for me during such days, but then I can't play. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6118/104) regarding leaving your guitar in the car has some useful info. From @Wheat's answer:

> ...changes in humidity that your physical body can't stand...this will severely fatigue the wood in your guitar
>
> ...will also weaken the glue holding the wooden plates and braces together, causing the guitar to slowly fall apart.
>
> ...the metal truss rod bows or warps positively or negatively every time it is exposed to a large swing in temperature.

Generally large **changes** in temperature or humidity are the problem. If your guitar is kept at a reasonably high temperature it will probably be fine (unless it gets hot enough that the glue melts!) - I wouldn't class 30 degrees as too high in this instance. The linked question discusses leaving a guitar in the car, which can get much hotter than that!

Comment: Let me point out that it can be "**over** 30 degrees"... outside. I'm not entirely sure what temperatures are inside - it can definitely feel like a lot, because it's so stuffy. I also saw the question / answer you linked before posting - my particular problem is about lower temperatures (cars can really be terrible during the summer, no doubts there) - thus I asked. :) I was hoping there's a definite "above XYZ degrees it's getting dangerous" rule. I'm definitely not worried about changes in temperature...

Comment: At really high temperatures you start to worry about glue melting, or metal parts bending, but it will depend on the type of guitar. A solid electric guitar may not be very sensitive, but an acoustic guitar could suffer a large effect.

Comment: I'd really like to know what "high temperatures" means. >_< Is it 40 degrees? 50? 60? I do remember someone mentioned that if a human is comfortable in a given temperature, then a guitar is OK. By this logic, 40 degrees is already starting to sound bad...